# How to search for exact pattern in a column using SQL LIKE operator?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like, postgresql-9.2

I have a table which is like below

```
    date    |                                                   tags                                                   
------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2018-10-24 | {"table": "bank_trans", "metric": "withdrawal", "location": "UK"}
 2018-10-24 | {"table": "bank_trans", "metric": "balance", "account_id": "477", "location": "ny", "country": "USA"}
 2018-10-24 | {"table": "bank_trans", "metric": "deposit", "location": "blr", "country": "IND"}
 2018-11-02 | {"table": "bank_trans", "metric": "balance", "account_id": "477"}
```

If I want a particular row that contains a search pattern something like below

```
select date, tags
from webhook_forecastmodel
where tags LIKE '%"table": "bank_trans"%' AND
      tags LIKE '%"metric": "balance"%' AND
      tags LIKE '%"account_id": "477"%';
```

In this case, I get back two results

```
    date    |                                                   tags                                                   
------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 2018-10-24 | {"table": "bank_trans", "metric": "balance", "account_id": "477", "location": "ny", "country": "USA"}

 2018-11-02 | {"table": "bank_trans", "metric": "balance", "account_id": "477"}
```

I understand the SQL query returns me the rows where the pattern matches.

But I only want the row that is exactly mentioned in the `LIKE` search pattern which is `"table": "bank_trans"`, `"metric": "balance"` and `"account_id": "477"` which leaves us with only one row

```
 2018-11-02 | {"table": "bank_trans", "metric": "balance", "account_id": "477"}
```

Is there any possible way that this could be achieved?

Comment: use json functions and operators, rather than `like` if the datatype of the column is `json`

Comment: Fix your data structure!  Don't treat a string as JSON.  More importantly, put values in columns that should be in columns; don't store them in strings.

Comment: PostgreSQL supports JSON as a column type. This would be much simpler if it were in a JSON column and using JSON functions rather than attempting to use pattern matching on the string or by normalizing the data into a structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: this question assumes an up-to-date Postgres version. It will not work on the outdated and no longer maintained version 9.2, but I'm leaving it here anyway for reference.

---

As mentioned in the comments don't use LIKE, use [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html). In order to be able to do that, you have to cast the value:

```
select date, tags
from webhook_forecastmodel
where tags::jsonb @> '{"table": "bank_trans"}'::jsonb 
  AND tags::jsonb @> '{"metric": "balance"}'::jsonb 
  AND tags::jsonb @> '{"account_id": "477"'}::jsonb;
```

The `@>` operator checks if the value on the left side contains the key/value pair on the right side.

---

The above would also return rows that contain more than those key/value pairs. If you want those that contain **exactly** those key/value pairs, use `=`

```
select date, tags
from webhook_forecastmodel
where tags::jsonb = '{"table": "bank_trans", 
                      "metric": "balance", 
                      "account_id": "477"}'::jsonb;
```

The `jsonb` data type normalizes the key/value pairs, so the order of the keys is irrelevant and the `=` comparison will work correctly.

Online example: https://rextester.com/LYXHUC20162

In the online example I have a different order of keys in the `tags` column compared to those used for the `=` operator to demonstrate that JSONB normalizes the JSON representation.

---

Given the nature of your data, it's probably better to define the column as `jsonb` to avoid all the casting.

Comment: Hey I get a syntax error for `jsonb`. My postgres version is 9.2. Is it because it was introduced in version 9.4?

Comment: @SouvikRay: correct, jsonb was introduced in 9.4. You should have mentioned it in your question that you are using an unsupported and outdated Postgres version. Neither of those two queries will work in 9.2. You should **really** plan an upgrade to Postgres 10 or 11 as soon as possible. Especially if that tag handling is important to you

Comment: thanks for the advice.Accepting this answer as I will upgrade to newer version of postgres.

Answer (score 1):

You have a really bad data structure.  Postgres supports a JSON type, so you could use that.  However, even with a JSON type, your question would be a bit challenging.

More importantly, you seem to want this information in *columns* so you should put it there.

Given the constraints in your question, there is a simple solution if I assume that `,` does not appear inside the key/value pairs.  If so:

```
select date, tags
from webhook_forecastmodel
where tags LIKE '%"table": "bank_trans"%' AND
      tags LIKE '%"metric": "balance"%' AND
      tags LIKE '%"account_id": "477"%' AND
      tags NOT LIKE '%,%,%,%';  -- not more than three key/value pairs
```